# Necessary and sufficient condition for existence of a graph homomorphism.

Tags: graph-theory

I got to deal with a beautiful problem regarding existence of a graph homomorphism. Here the problem is,

Let $Z$ be a graph having set of integers, $\Bbb{Z}$ as its vertex set and edge set $E$ of $Z$ is given by, $E=\{\{i,i+1\}:i\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

**Problem** Let $G$ be a finite connected simple graph. Then show that, there is a graph homomorphism from $G$ to $Z$ if and only if $G$ has no odd length cycle.

**Proof** $(\implies)$

Let $f:G\rightarrow Z$ be a homomorphism and if possible let $G$ has an odd cycle $v_1v_2\dots v_nv_1$, where $n$ is odd. Then $f(v_1)f(v_2)\dots f(v_n)f(v_1)$ is an odd closed walk in $Z$. Now any odd closed walk contains a cycle, but $Z$ does not contain any cycle. Hence we arrived at a contradiction. Therefore $G$ has no odd cycle.

( $\Longleftarrow$ )

Let $x_0\in V(G)$, define  $V_0=\{x_0\}$ and
$V_i=\{x\in V:xv\in E$ for some $v\in V_{i-1},x\notin V_j$ for any $j<i\}$ for $i>0$.

Definition of $V_i$ gives that, elements of $V_i$ does not contain in $V_j$ for any $j<i$. Thus, $V_i\cap V_j=\phi$ for all $i\neq j$.

If possible let $x\in S=V\setminus (V_0\cup V_1\cup\dots \cup V_m)$. Then $x\not \leftrightarrow y$ for any $y\in V_i$, for all $i\geq0$, because otherwise, $x\in V_{i+1}$. Hence $<S>$ and $<V_0\cup V_1\cup\dots \cup V_m>$ are in different components of $G$. But this is not possible because $G$ is connected. So $\{V_i\}_{i\geq0}$ is a partition of $V(G)$.

Let $f:V\rightarrow Z$ defined by, $f(x)=i$ if $x\in V_i$. To show $f$ is a homomorphism, let $x\leftrightarrow y$ in $G$. Then two cases arise.

Case-$1$: $f(x)=f(y)$($=i$, say). In this case we have, $x,y\in V_i$.
Now $x\in V_i$ gives there is a path $x_0v_1v_2\dots v_{i-1}x$ in $G$, where $v_k\in V_k, k=1,2,\dots,i-1$.

Similarly $y\in V_i$ gives there is a path $x_0u_1u_2\dots u_{i-1}y$ in $G$, where $u_k\in V_k, k=1,2,\dots,i-1$.

Thus we obtain, $x_0v_1v_2\dots v_{i-1}xyu_{i-1}\dots u_1x_0$ is a closed walk in $G$ of length $2i+1$ (odd), which contains an odd cycle. This is a contradiction, because $G$ does not contain any odd cycle.

Thus we left with other case $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Let $f(x)=i$, $f(y)=j$ and $j<i$. Now $y\in V_j$ and $x\leftrightarrow y$ implies $x\in V_{j+1}$. Hence $i=j+1$. Thus, $f(x)\leftrightarrow f(y)$ in $Z$, which proves $f$ is a homomorphism.

Please check it whether there is any flaw, because in combinatorics proofs sometimes I miss something. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof works (taking the claim that any odd closed walk contains a cycle for granted, though that claim is also worth proving), but there is a simpler argument.

The graph $Z$ has a homomorphism to $K_2$, the graph with two vertices $\{0,1\}$ and an edge between them. The homomorphism sends $i \in \mathbb Z$ to $i \bmod 2$.

Therefore if there is a homomorphism to $G \to Z$, the composition $G \to Z \to K_2$ gives us a homomorphism $G \to K_2$. On the other hand, any homomorphism $G \to K_2$ can also be thought of a homomorphism $G \to Z$ that simply has $\{0,1\}$ as its image. In other words, there is a homomorphism $G \to Z$ if and only if there is a homomorphism $G \to K_2$.

Finally, a homomorphism $G \to K_2$ exists if and only if $G$ is $2$-colorable, or bipartite; bipartite graphs are exactly the graphs with no odd cycles.

Comment: The proof is very very good. Thank you.